# Isn't it possible to use an array of a custom datatype with CVC4?

Tags: smt, cvc4

using latest cvc4 as of 2018-07-10, this code:

```
(set-info :smt-lib-version 2.6)
(set-logic ALL)
(declare-datatypes
  ( (Type 0) )
  ( ((bool) (number)
     (tuple (tuple-type (Array Int Type)))) ))
```

produces this output from cvc4:

```
(error "Parse Error: Symbol 'Type' not declared as a type
   (tuple (tuple-type (Array Int Type)))) ))
                                 ^
")
```

The same datatype declaration is accepted by Z3.
Isn't this supposed to work? Is that a bug?
Any work-around ?

Comment: This is most likely a CVC4 bug/shortcoming. Please report it at: https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/issues

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/issues/2161